# Pycharm "Please select App Engine SDK directory" Problem

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, pycharm, google-app-engine-python

I am trying to set up Pycharm for a google app engine project but the "create" button on the Pycharm New Project window remains greyed out no matter what I try whenever I select the app engine SDK directory. I've reinstalled everything several times through Powershell, for all users, for a single user, I've tried every directory and everything suggested on every stack overflow question regarding this issue, but nothing works. I don't know what to do to fix it, and I'm out of ideas. What file is Pycharm even expecting to see, does anyone know?

Comment: What flavour of PyCharm? CE or Pro? A while back (v5.0.6) only the Pro version supported GAE projects. Also it worked with the GAE SDK, not the gcloud SDK and the support was rather limited for more complex scenarios - I was still deploying using the SDK CLI, PyCharm couldn't handle multiple services. I didn't re-check w/ more recent versions, thinks may have changed.

Comment: Pycharm Professional version 2020 2.1

Comment: I know you've tried many things already but check the soltuion from [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203458964-Pycharm-Professional-Grayed-Out-Create-Button-Google-App-Engine) for if you have GAE component installed.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked my latest GAE project (which I didn't touch in quite a while, but appears to still be working).

I currently run PyCharm 2019.2.5 Pro (Linux).
The setting points to `/usr/local/google_appengine` which is a symlink to the directory where I extracted the [original App Engine SDK for Python 2](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/setting-up-environment#python_linux) (bottom of the page).

I'm using a symlink so that I don't have to change it when I update the SDK (donno if that works for Windows):

```
> ls -l /usr/local/google_appengine
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Nov 23  2019 /usr/local/google_appengine -> google_appengine.87
> ls -l /usr/local/google_appengine/
total 100
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2305 Jan  1  1980 api_server.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3127 Jan  1  1980 appcfg.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3127 Jan  1  1980 backends_conversion.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   156 Jan  1  1980 BUGS
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3127 Jan  1  1980 bulkload_client.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3127 Jan  1  1980 bulkloader.py
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    18 Jan  1  1980 demos
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2305 Jan  1  1980 dev_appserver.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3127 Jan  1  1980 download_appstats.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3127 Jan  1  1980 endpointscfg.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3127 Jan  1  1980 gen_protorpc.py
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    88 Jan  1  1980 google
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1284 Jan  1  1980 lib
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  5922 Jan  1  1980 LICENSE
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    72 Jan  1  1980 new_project_template
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    46 Jan  1  1980 php
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2305 Jan  1  1980 php_cli.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2305 Jan  1  1980 _php_runtime.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2305 Jan  1  1980 _python_runtime.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  8393 Jan  1  1980 README
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   138 Jan  1  1980 RELEASE_NOTES
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3127 Jan  1  1980 remote_api_shell.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2115 Jan  1  1980 run_tests.py
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    36 Jan  1  1980 tools
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   264 Jan  1  1980 VERSION
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12076 Jan  1  1980 wrapper_util.py
```